# builtins.AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'get_ticks'

Tags: python, pygame

what is the reason I am getting an error here?

```
while running:
    for e in event.get(): 
        if e.type == QUIT:
            running = False
        if e.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:               
            if e.button == 1: 
                start_time = time.get_ticks()
                if prev_pos != None:   
                    draw.line(screen, YELLOW, prev_pos, e.pos)
                if prev_pos == None:
                    draw.line(screen, YELLOW, (0,0), e.pos)
                prev_pos = e.pos
                if start_time and pygame.time.get_ticks() - start_time < 2000:
                    draw.line(screen, BLACK, prev_pos, e.pos)
                draw.circle(screen, YELLOW, e.pos, 5)
```

I am just trying to make something appear and then disappear after 2 seconds, but why do I keep getting this error?

Comment: Where is `time` is initialized? Or is it imported from [`pygame`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/time.html)?

Comment: @CristianCiupitu it is imported from pygame.

Comment: @Rabbid76 I tried that, it give me an error - 'pygame' not defined

Comment: Probably you have a variable named `time` in your application. This variabel covers the module `time`. Rename the variable.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is that you do a wildcard import of the pygame module:

```
from pygame import *
```

and then somewhere in your code you overwrite the `time` variable with an integer, something like:

```
time = 0
```

So when you try to access `pygame.time.get_ticks()` the `.time`-part no longer references pygame's time module, but your integer.

IMHO, just never use `from ... import *`. Python has enough other pitfalls.